# I'm trying to compile a Kotlin project on fire with the "kotlinc Main.kt -d hello.jar" command and I'm getting this error unresolved reference: Bird

Tags: java, kotlin, jar

My program has two classes Main.kt and Bird.kt

Main.kt :

`

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val bird = Bird()
    bird.echo()
}
```

`
Bird.kt

`

```
class Bird {
    fun echo() {
        println("Hello")
    }
}
```

`

Command : Main.kt -d hello.jar
Error

```
Main.kt:2:16: error: unresolved reference: Bird
    val bird = Bird()
               ^
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Command :     "Main.kt -d hello.jar"
Error "Main.kt:2:16: error: unresolved reference: Bird
    val bird = Bird()
               ^"

Comment: This seems obvious, but you don't seem to have also compiled Bird.kt...

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```bash
kotlinc *kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
```

In order to compile all `*.kt` files.